# Что нужно знать Java EE developer'у?

Tags: java, java-ee

Что и в каком порядке изучать для Java EE?

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что входит в Java EE. Ну и на сегодня нужно изучать Jakarta EE (в общем то тоже самое, но нет). Многое зависит от того, что вы хотите разрабатывать. Советую вам начать с DI и IOC (почитать про бины CDI). Считаю, что это краеугольный камень EE

Comment: Spring хорошая альтернатива Java EE, но есть Вы все же хотите работать с Java EE, то обязаны прочитать эту [книгу]( https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Java-EE-Expert-Voice/dp/143024626X?crid=212UHQAEP2ENO&keywords=beginning+java+ee+7&qid=1537695874&sprefix=begining+java+ee+&sr=8-1&ref=mp_s_a_1_1) (есть на русском). В ней очень хорошо описано все то, что должен знать разработчик использующий Java EE.

Answer (score 2):

- *CDI*

  Внедрение зависимостей и все что с этим связано.
- *Servlets, JSF*

  Сервлеты и Java Server Faces - более удобная технология(по мнению Oracle) для java разработчиков, принятая для замены HTML.
- *EJB*

  Enterprise Java Beans. Краеугольный камень Java EE.
- *JPA*

  Java Persistanse API - спецификация для работы с базами данных. Наиболее популярный фреимворк - Hibernate.
- *JMS*

  Java Message System

Ну и дополнительно - SOAP и REST.

Что входит в Java EE, написано в [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#API_%D0%B2_Java_EE).

Еще можно добавить js/css/html.

Comment: Ну вот вас попросили про Java EE, а вы про около того

Comment: Java EE программист работает с Java EE, а не со спрингом

Comment: Пишу более 5 лет на Java. Никогда с Томом и Спрингом не работал. Моя жизнь прожита зря )=

Comment: @Suvitruf ну, я имел ввиду работу с серверами. А tomcat - т.к. один из самых распространенных серверов.

Comment: @Suvitruf посмотрел вакансии JavaEE-разработчика на hh - где-то в 70% требуется Tomcat/Jetty

Comment: @AntonSorokin я предпочитаю netty.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE developer'у нужно знать как минимум Java Core и входящие в Java EE стандарты.

Answer (score 0):

имхо, начинать нужно с туториала актуальной на момент изучения версии (пока Jakarta EE https://jakarta.ee/ не обзавелась нормальным туториалом, можно пользоваться все еще доступной версией от Oracle: Java EE 7 tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ )